# What does 'Truth-level' mean in Particle Physics?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, terminology

I am sorry to ask an obvious question but I have tried looking this up on Google and cannot get an answer. In particle physics, when it is said that something is 'truth-level', what does that mean?  For example, if someone is referring to a 'truth-level' jet or a plot of jet masses at truth level, could someone explain in layman's terms what this actually means?

Comment: Link or reference to an example that uses the word ['truth-level'](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=truth+level)?

Comment: I don't need to reference it, it's common terminology, I am just asking what it means.  It is used everywhere in particle physics.  Reference: LHC

Comment: Do you mean [confidence level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval)?

Comment: @Qmechanic It seems to be simulation jargon, truth level vs detector level. A truth level simulation is a particle simulation that doesn't include a detector?

Comment: I'm not really sure, in particle it seems like everyone refers to 'truth-level', this could be jargon for confidence level, but no-one explains it anywhere.

Comment: In a simulation events are generated and then you would get for example a shower of jets or something like that, which can then be analysed and passed on to a detector, so it could be truth-level jets they are talking about raw jets before they get passed on to the detector.

Comment: Ie. just the jets that are 'there' in the shower, without necessarily being detected or passed on to simulations of experimental equipment.  These jets could have their own patterns which would then be validated at detector level, so this could be what is meant.

Comment: "Truth level" is pretty much synonymous with "generator level"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this proposal:](https://indico.cern.ch/event/351610/contributions/826556/attachments/695528/955012/TruthParticleSessionSlides.pdf)

> Define “truth” objects, e.g. stable particles entering the detector, as close as  possible to physics objects reconstructed in the detector

It seems to be an effort to understand detector effects better than up to now.

i.e "true" particles from the interaction vertex hit a detector, and are the source of a number of secondary interactions that are measured in the detector and extrapolated to the true/real  entrant. Example: a true photon hits the electromagnetic calorimeter. A shower of electrons are generated in the detector and measured to extrapolate back at the true one photon entry.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is in the context of simulation. In actual data you never have access to the truth-level information unless you are some sort of omniscient being.

Comment: Yes, of course, I am only talking about simulations here.